# How do you find a value that does not appear in the keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out which values in my dictionary do not appear in the keys as well. How can I do this?

Comment: whats the first line ? `for value in relationship.values():` i think its a typo , you need to remove it !

Comment: I tried to remove it but It is still producing incorrect results!

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the fastest way, but it's simple.

```
# Make a set of of the values
prey = set(relationship.values())

# Find the intersection of predators and prey (elements that are both keys and values)
both = prey.intersection(relationship)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple to test if a value is or isn't in the set of keys; just use `in`/`not in`.

```
for value in relationship.values():
    if value not in relationship:
        # value is not in the set of keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
producers = [val for val in relationship.values() if val not in relationship]
```

or set comprehension if you don't want duplicates:

```
producers = {val for val in relationship.values() if val not in relationship}
```

Then you can easily print them (or anyother nunber of operaitons):

```
for val in producers:
    print(val)
```

This solution is useful if you want to store the values to print later or keep on hand for any other reason.